# Can a Collection in Java hold different children classes?

Tags: java, collections, abstract-class

I have three classes. Class `A` (an abstract class) is the parent for both class `B` and class `C`.

I need to have a container that can hold objects of either `B` or `C` at the same time.

I tried to do this

```
ArrayList<A> myCollection = new ArrayList<A>();
```

and then

```
myCollection.add(b); //b is an instance of class B
```

I get this error:

> The method add(A) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (B)

Is there a way that I can store objects of both class `B` and `C` in my `ArrayList`? Or is there another data structure that I can use?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the declaration correctly? A pure ArrayList, with no generic parameter, should accept any object reference.

Comment: Have you read anything about generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code bellow:

```
ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();

// Adding items
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
```

Comment: and consider referring objects by their interfaces, you should favor the use of interfaces rather than classes to refer to objects

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see this:

```
public class Fo {

  static class A{}
  static class B extends A{}

  static void f() {
    List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
    as.add(new B());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
 ArrayList<? extends A> myCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: and consider referring objects by their interfaces, you should favor the use of interfaces rather than classes to refer to objects,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a list of the super class.

```
List<A> l = new ArrayList<A>();
        l.add(new B());
        l.add(new C());
```

that is **100**% correct, you have a list of the super class, and since **B** and **C** are Objects of the class **A**, then is valid...

and consider referring objects by their interfaces, you should favor the use of interfaces rather than classes to refer to objects,

> If you get into the habit of using interfaces as types, your program will be
>   much more flexible. If you decide that you want to switch
>   implementations, all you have to do is change the class name in the
>   constructor (or use a different static factory).